# PyTorch: CUDA is not available

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, cuda, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to run PyTorch on a NVIDIA Jetson Nano and my project requires me to use CUDA. I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.10.6. I followed this [guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-6-0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=arm64-sbsa&Compilation=Native&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=18.04&target_type=deb_local) to install CUDA 11.6. Then using the instructions on [PyTorch.org](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) I installed PyTorch using this command:

```
pip install torch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu116
```

But then when I try to verify it, it's not available:

```
(env) $ python
Python 3.10.6 (main, Aug  2 2022, 15:11:03) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>>
```

here's the CUDA version:

```
(env) $ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Dec_17_18:16:35_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.6, V11.6.55
Build cuda_11.6.r11.6/compiler.30794723_0
```

And here is some information from PyTorch. Notice how it says `CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect`.

```
(env) $ python -m torch.utils.collect_env
PyTorch version: 1.12.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (aarch64)
GCC version: (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: version 3.10.2
Libc version: glibc-2.27

Python version: 3.10.6 (main, Aug  2 2022, 15:11:03) [GCC 7.5.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-4.9.253-tegra-aarch64-with-glibc2.27
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.6.55
GPU models and configuration: Could not collect
Nvidia driver version: Could not collect
cuDNN version: Probably one of the following:
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_infer.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_adv_train.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_cnn_train.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_infer.so.8.2.1
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcudnn_ops_train.so.8.2.1
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.23.1
[pip3] torch==1.12.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.13.0
[conda] Could not collect
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried compiling pytorch from source or using the [whl files from nvidia](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pytorch-for-jetson-version-1-11-now-available/72048)?

Comment: The way that you installed CUDA on your jetson nano is incorrect.  I don't know how to fix that except by reflashing your Jetson.  The primary method to install CUDA is via jetpack.  Once you have installed via Jetpack 4.6 or newer, you can use the package manager to upgrade the CUDA version, if you wish.  After that, [this](https://pytorch.org/blog/running-pytorch-models-on-jetson-nano/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading the compiled whl file from nvidia and installing it with pip did the trick (as suggested by @FlyingTeller).

```
wget https://nvidia.box.com/shared/static/p57jwntv436lfrd78inwl7iml6p13fzh.whl -O torch-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl
pip install numpy torch-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_aarch64.whl
```