# Cannot convince Pytorch to install with Cuda (Windows 11)

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, anaconda

I am trying to install PyTorch with Cuda using Anaconda3, on Windows 11:

- My GPU is RTX **3060**.
- My conda environment is Python **3.10.13**.
- nvidia-smi outputs Driver Version: **551.23**, CUDA Version: **12.4**.

What I tried:

- Following the instructions on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/, picking CUDA 12.1 (and 11.8)
- Reading through a bunch of posts on https://discuss.pytorch.org/ (including https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-cuda-is-available-gives-false/197333)
- Reading through a bunch of posts on SO (e.g. [PyTorch: CUDA is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250147/pytorch-cuda-is-not-available))

Many articles say that I don't need to have a independently installed CUDA so I uninstalled the system-wide version - but it predictably didn't make a difference. No matter what I try, `torch.cuda.is_available()` is always false.

I think my conclusion is that the nVidia driver must match the version of CUDA, but for me it's counterintuitive. I've always trained myself to install the latest and greatest nVidia driver (I use my machine for gaming as much as I want to use it for ML) - is my understanding correct, and the only way to get PyTorch to work with CUDA is to *downgrade* my GPU driver from 551.23 to something that supports CUDA 12.1?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the driver, and no you don’t need to downgrade it

Comment: If it’s not the driver, is there a magic incantation that can convince PyTorch to run with Cuda ? Quite surprised things don’t just work out of the box with the “latest and greatest”.

Comment: The first question is are you *really* sure you have installed a CUDA accelerated build of PyTorch. That is about 30% of all the questions I see about this.

Comment: This is the command I used, straight from pytorch.org: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=12.1 -c pytorch -c nvidia`. I also tried some variations like using Pytorch nightly and trying 11.8 instead of 12.1, but really, that should be all there is to it, no? After I run conda list, I see "py3.10_cuda12.1_cudnn8_0" in the list so I am assuming I do have the righ flavour. Still torch.cuda.is_available() returns False.

Comment: What does torch.cuda.get_arch_list() return? If it doesn't return anything, you have a non CUDA enabled build installed somewhere

Comment: Bingo, this is it! I had a system-wide torch installed (leftover of me doing things with vanilla Python instead of using environments - I knew it was a bad idea, but this is a good illustration why one should always use something like Anaconda or VirtualEnv for anything remotely non-trivial). Thanks! Do you want to post this as an answer? "Make sure you don't have any other torch installs, especially global ones".

Comment: It's your system, you answer. I'm just guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution - find and uninstall non-CUDA torch installations!**

In my case, the issue was caused by another system-wide installation of torch. Before I started using Anaconda, I was under the silly impression that I can get away with using a vanilla Python. Whatmore, I was using a mixture of system-wide and user-installed packages - a nice recipe for disaster.

*@talonmies offered a great tip: printing out the output of `torch.cuda.get_arch_list()`. In my case, it was an empty list `[]`, indicating a wrong torch library was loaded.*

I ran pip list using regular Python outside of the Anaconda environment and lo and behold, I had the non-cuda torch installed! I have used pip to uninstall everything that had to do with torch/pytorch (and noticed some weird ~orch leftovers that I forcefully purged) - and then all was good.

Lesson learned - when doing complex things with Python (e.g. ML) always start with a virtual environment (Anaconda, Miniconda, VirtualEnv, what have you) or you will regret it later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Python expert...I've learned and forgotten Python twice...but I guess I'm on to round 3.

After removing existing pytorch installations with `pip uninstall torch torchvision torchaudio` and `pip cache purge`, and learning that CUDA 12.1 is the only version of CUDA 12 supported by looking [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/), I ran `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121` and finally CUDA worked with pytorch.